# Phabricator SES Emails?

Tags: php, phabricator

My mailers.json file:

```
[
 {
"key": "ExampleOrg",
"type": "ses",
"options": {
  "endpoint": "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  "access-key": "....................",
    "secret-key": ".............................."
}
 }
]
```

then cd to Phabricator installation

```
./bin/config set --stdin cluster.mailers < mailers.json
```

I restarted apache2, but still all the emails are pending in Queue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing this issue change the endpoint url

from: "endpoint": "***email-smtp***.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
to: "endpoint": "***email***.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",

Phabricator expects the http endpoint url and not the smtp

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a test email using

```
bin/mail send-test --to alincoln --subject hi < body.txt
```

it will show you the error if there are any, in my case it was the `php-xml`
installing it solved the issue

```
sudo apt install php-xml
```